# Adding loop device support to existing kernel

Tags: android, kernel, kernel-module

I have looked everywhere for an answer to this and haven't been able to find anything. I want to be able to run linux ontop of android 7.0 on my rooted nexus 6p but all methods that i know of require loop device support. I downloaded an app from the play store called loop device checker to check if it was possible and it says that my device does not support loop. I am running the latest EX Kernel. I tried it on the stock and franco kernel as well with no luck. Does anyone know anything about this? One thing i was hoping i could do is edit the EX kernel to add loop support but i dont have any idea how i would go about doing this. If anyone knows of a way to edit the kernel to add this and could give me steps that would be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how much this will help, but might get you going in the right direction.  [This](https://source.android.com/setup/building-kernels) is a good resource to learn how to build your own kernel from an existing one.

As for loop device support, I'm just going to reference [an answer on Quora](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-add-loop-device-support-in-the-existing-Android-Kernel) which cites the [Building Kernels guide](https://source.android.com/setup/building-kernels):

> You need one additional step right after the make foo_defconfig. You
>   have to do a make menuconfig *after* the make foo_defconfig. In the
>   resultant menu You need to enable Device Drivers -> Block Devices ->
>   Loopback device support.

Hope this helps.